# Average of certain values in pandas dataframe with if condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, average

| index | column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 2 | 1.2 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 2.2 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 3 | 3.1 |
| 5 | 3.3 | 3.5 |
| 6 | 3.6 | 3.8 |
| 7 | 3.9 | 4.0 |
| 8 | 4.0 | 4.0 |
| 9 | 4.0 | 4.1 |
| 10 | 4.1 | 4.0 |

I created a moving average with df.rolling(). But I just want to have the average of the "constant" value (here around 4), that is not changing more than 10% any more.
My first approach was to try it with an if condition, but my attemps to just create an average of certain values in the column failed.
Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: I think there are "many possible cases" here. Do you want a moving average? a sum average? etc. You can always "select" the data first that meets the ±10%, operate on those, and merge them back to the original dataframe

Comment: I would like to have a moving average. How can I implement the 10% condition? I just know how to chose by name...

Comment: My bad, I understood ±10% of the final value. I am not sure I understand how it should look like. Can you provide a "desired output" column? Usually understanding the question is the hardest part :)

Comment: I added a picture up there from my real data. What I want is to have an average of a value that gets constant. If the value is not x% different from the value 1 oder 10 or whatever values before, I want it to be added to the values that I will make an average over. Is that understandable?

Comment: Probably, you could do something like an average of `tail(10)`, and then select with something like `df[(df.value > 0.9*last_n_averaged) & (df.value < 1.1*last_n_averaged)]` and then apply the rolling average on those ones